# Using "tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath" in tandem with prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, row, segue

I have a project utilizing storyboards that uses UITableView in tandem with a Navigation Controller. Its layout is similar to apple's iOS Address Book where there is a table of objects, and clicking on a cell pushes a view onto the navcontroller with that objects's details (properties). I am having trouble using the prepareForSegue method in harmony with the table view's didSelectRowAtIndex. I need a way for the prepareForSegue to know about the row passed in didSelectRowAtIndex so i can pass it's properties to the detail view controller being pushed since prepareForSegue gets called **before** didSelectRowAtIndex does. If possible I would still like to use the storyboard segue but if there isn't a way i can progamatically push/pop. There is another question similar to this on stackoverflow but it never really was answered, it kind of just rambled on.

If you know a work-around please let me know, **thank you**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` at all. You can get the index path in `prepareForSegue:` like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```